# Problem with DVDs

Tags: dvd

When I try to play video DVDs on Ubuntu 11.10 always get this error message: *"Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed."* I tried to solve this with adding restricted-extras and libdvdcss2. But i still get this message. Any ideas to fix that?

Comment: Try to install libdvdread. Better yet read this http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Oneiric#DVD_Playback_Capability

Comment: Should this question not be closed as and exact duplicate? There are dozens of related questions...

Answer (score 2):

Install VLC it works great

[image]

There is a daily build PPA from the VLC team, add it following these steps

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

Update and upgrade / install VLC

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html